# ¿Porque me Marca Undefined index en PHP Usando $_FILES para Imagenes?

Tags: php, mysql, html5

Bueno mi problema es que estoy intentando almacenar imágenes en mi base de datos en mysql esto usando el lenguaje de php y me apareces esta notificación

```
   Notice: Undefined index: file-1[] in C:\xampp\htdocs\Hidtruth\PHP\configuracion\save.php on line 8
```

Aqui esta el codigo de mi input de tipo archivo.

```
<input type="file" name="file-1[]" id="file-1" class="inputfile inputfile-1" data-multiple-caption="{count} files selected" multiple />
```

Aqui esta el codigo de mi captura en php de mi supuesto archivo

```
$imagen=$_FILES["file-1[]"]["temp_name"];
echo $imagen;
```

Si se dan cuenta se puede apreciar que hago un echo hacia la imagen para ver que es lo que obtengo pero me sale el error de arriba. Lo que quiero es que me de la ruta de mi archivo para después copiarlo a una carpeta de mi proyecto.

Comment: tienes el metodo de envio de datos en tu formulario? algo asi como esto **<form action="upload.php" method="post" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">´**

Comment: recuerda que al agregar **enctype="multipart/form-data"** este te permitira subir archivos

Answer (score 1):

Cuando defines el `name`del input en el HTML, le das un valor de array:

`<input type="file" name="file-1[]" id="file-1" class="inputfile inputfile-1" data-multiple-caption="{count} files selected" multiple />`

Por lo que al ser enviado por el formulario, lo va a hacer en forma de array y así es como lo vas a recibir en el POST de PHP.

El índice del array `$_FILES` cuando lo recibas será `file-1` pero el contenido va a ser un array, entonces para el primer archivo recibido, tendrás que indicar el sub-índice de la siguiente forma:

`$imagen=$_FILES["file-1"][0]["tmp_name"];`

Para que te des una idea mejor, podés empezar por imprimir el contenido de la variable `$_FILES` para ver lo que estás recibiendo también, eso siempre ayuda:

`print_r($_FILES);`

También te recomiendo que leas la respuesta de Arturo Belanio Lima que aporta información relacionada que te puede ser útil.

Answer (score 0):

Que tal, de la forma que obtengas la variable, ya sea por POST o por GET, puedes intentar esto:
Por POST

```
$variable = isset($_POST['file-1[]'])? $_POST['file-1[]']:'';
```

Por GET

```
$variable = isset($_GET['file-1[]'])? $_GET['file-1[]']:'';
```

Answer (score 0):

Hay varios errores los cuales están causando el problema que indicas (y otros que todavía no te aparecen).

Si es que en HTML defines un input para que suba múltiples imágenes/archivos (como en tu caso con file-1[]), desde PHP **no** debes poner **[]** de tal manera que quede así:

```
$imagen=$_FILES["file-1"]["temp_name"];
```

Otro posible error que puedes tener es que no estés enviando la propiedad enctype en el formulario. Debería verse así la declaración que tengas del formulario:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Por último, no existe "temp_name", lo que existe en PHP es "tmp_name". Corrige aquél error también:

```
$imagen=$_FILES["file-1"]["tmp_name"];
```

Acá puedes ver un pequeño artículo donde se describe cómo subir imágenes con PHP y un formulario web:

http://blog.aulaformativa.com/consultorio-desarrollo-web/